# How to pass complex arguments to rostopic (Python subprocess)?

Tags: ros, ros-comm, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to call `ros_comm` tools (mainly `rostopic` to publish messages right now) via Python `subprocess` and pass complex YAML arguments (nested, containing message fields of all field types, etc.) to it.

Let's say I want to publish messages of type `geometry_msgs/PointStamped`

```
$ rosmsg show geometry_msgs/PointStamped
std_msgs/Header header
  uint32 seq
  time stamp
  string frame_id
geometry_msgs/Point point
  float64 x
  float64 y
  float64 z
```

on a topic `/pt`using explicit YAML dictionary syntax like described in the [wiki section "4.3 Command-line and messages (dictionaries)"](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/YAMLCommandLine#Command-line_and_messages_.28dictionaries.29) which would be called on the command line like follows:

```
rostopic pub pt geometry_msgs/PointStamped '{header: {stamp: now, frame_id: base_link}, point: {x: 1.0, y: 2.0, z: 3.0}}'
```

Using the YAML list syntax works well but is not really convenient to work with and is limited to easier cases I guess:

```
import subprocess
yaml_list_header = '[0, now, base_link]'
yaml_list_point = '[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]'
sp = subprocess.Popen(['rostopic', 'pub', 'pt', 'geometry_msgs/PointStamped', yaml_list_header, yaml_list_point, '-r', '2'])
```

---

**EDIT:**
Probably not obvious... nesting with YAML list syntax is possible as well.

```
import subprocess
yaml_list_header = '[0, [0, 0], base_link]'
yaml_list_point = '[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]'
sp = subprocess.Popen(['rostopic', 'pub', 'pt', 'geometry_msgs/PointStamped', yaml_list_header, yaml_list_point, '-r', '2'])
```

---

What's the best approach (most flexible, least error prone) to publish messages via `rostopic` called via Python `subprocess`? It is probably best to pass the `cmd` as list to `subprocess.Popen(cmd)`. (Not to use `shlex.split(<cmd-as-string>)` to generate `cmd` for `subprocess.Popen(cmd)` due to little control about what the result looks like and if it suites the syntax.) (As YAML is a valid super-set of JSON it's probably  possible to use some string to JSON parser for conversion.)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/294099/how-to-pass-complex-arguments-to-rostopic-(python-subprocess)?/) by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 468 on 2018-06-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-14**:
I'm not sure it's a best practice (I dislike using the command line tools from Python/C++ in any case), but what about using the regular msg classes, populate their fields, serialise to yaml and pass that string to `rostopic pub`?

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-06-14**:
I dislike using the command line tools as well. However for now it is the best approach to get fast results. " serialise to yaml and pass that string to rostopic pub?" That's exactly what I don't know how to do in detail yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I definitely agree with @gvdhoorn that this is likely not best practice to begin with, but his suggestion of serializing to YAML seems to work great. Example:

```
import yaml
import subprocess
from geometry_msgs.msg import PointStamped
import time

p = PointStamped()
p.header.frame_id = "test"
p.point.x = 2.0
y = yaml.load(str(p))
args = ['rostopic', 'pub', '/pt', 'geometry_msgs/PointStamped', '-r', '2', str(y)]
sp = subprocess.Popen(args)
time.sleep(2)
sp.kill()
```

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2018-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-06-15**:
I totally agree. Shelling out is not best practice. I changed the question title accordingly. Thx for the example. As this answer is matching the current question title I'll accept this one. Thx for all other response so far as well (@ahendrix, @gvdhoorn).

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-06-15**:
Side note: If you want to get an insight into messages (here) `PointStamped` go for:

```
In [1]: from geometry_msgs.msg import PointStamped
In [2]: PointStamped??
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd strongly recommend using the rospy API instead of shelling out to the command-line tool.

```
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import PointStamped

p = PointStamped()
p.header.frame_id = 'test'
p.point.x = 2.0

rospy.init_node('point_pub')
pub = rospy.Publisher('pt', PointStamped, queue_size=10)

for i in range(4):
    pub.publish(p)
    rospy.sleep(0.5)
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-06-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1